# conversion of javascript object and deleting some fields

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I am working on a project in which it needs to convert List of javascript object data

```
 [{
            "_id": "UID",
            "email": "example.example.com",
            "password": "password Hash",
            "username": "username",
            "createdAt": "date",
            
        },...]
```

convert the above to

```
[{
         "username":"username", 
         "_id":"uid",
     },...]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Array.prototype.map` and remap the original entity collection into a new collection using a transformer.

I'm going to avoid arrow functions and object literal returns to avoid confusion.

```js
var users = [{
  "_id": "UID",
  "email": "example.example.com",
  "password": "password Hash",
  "username": "username",
  "createdAt": "date",
},
{
  "_id": "UID",
  "email": "example.example.com",
  "password": "password Hash",
  "username": "username",
  "createdAt": "date",
}]

var userTransformer = function(user) {
  return {
    "_id": user._id,
    "username": user.username,
  }
}

var transformedUsers = users.map(userTransformer);

console.log(transformedUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [{
  "_id": "UID",
  "email": "example.example.com",
  "password": "password Hash",
  "username": "username",
  "createdAt": "date",

}]

const output = input.map(({
  _id,
  username
}) => ({
  _id,
  username
}))
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
  {
    _id: "UID",
    email: "example.example.com",
    password: "password Hash",
    username: "username",
    createdAt: "date",
  },
  {
    _id: "UID",
    email: "example.example.com",
    password: "password Hash",
    username: "username",
    createdAt: "date",
  },
  {
    _id: "UID",
    email: "example.example.com",
    password: "password Hash",
    username: "username",
    createdAt: "date",
  },
];

arr = arr.map(({ _id, username })=>{
    return {
        _id:_id.toLowerCase(),
        username
    }
});

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
list = [{
    "_id": "UID",
    "email": "example.example.com",
    "password": "password Hash",
    "username": "username",
    "createdAt": "date",
    
}]
list=list.map(item=>{
    return {"username":item.username,
    "_id":item._id
}
})
console.log(list)
```

you can use map function mapping it to a new list with desired field

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to make changes without ***mutating the original state*** -

using the [`...`] spread operator of javascript language

```js
var z ;
z=[{
     "_id": "UID",
            "email": "example.example.com",
            "password": "password Hash",
            "username": "username",
            "createdAt": "date",
},{
 "_id": "UID",
            "email": "example1.example1.com",
            "password": "password Hash1",
            "username": "username111",
            "createdAt": "date11",
            },
            {
 "_id": "UID",
            "email": "example2.example.com",
            "password": "password Hash22",
            "username": "username22",
            "createdAt": "date222",
            },
]
var l = [...z];
l[0] = {
"_id": "UID",
            "email": "TechnicalGurujiYT.com",
            "password": "Binks69",
            "username": "Ketank18",
            "createdAt": "23rd Mar",
}
console.log('z',z);
console.log('l',l);
```

output-
[image]
TRY IT -
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GQGVSY1G0O7C